# jupyter equivalent of %%bash in windows

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

In my home computer (mac) when I want to use the terminal I normally write the following in a cell

```py
%%bash
pwd
```

or

```py
%%bash
pip install package
```

Now I am on a Windows computer and I want to do the same, but I get an error

[image]

How can I do work with the Anaconda prompt inside jupypter with a Windows computer?

PD: I am aware that I can do this `!dir` but I am looking for working with the prompt not just one line

Comment: try exclamation mark in cell `!pwd`

Comment: !pwd wont work but !dir it does. I am looking for more interaction with the anaconda prompt, in this way I can only write one line